# Setting variable to output of awk function

Tags: awk

I have defined an `awk` function `dgrul` that returns a string.

I have a variable which I want to set to the output of the function `dgrul`.  How can I do this?

Here is the function

```
function dgrul(categr,     rl)
 {
  if ( ! categr ) { categr = "POSIX" }
  rl="[[:digit:]]"
  return rl
 }
```

I want to set the value `digt_rl` so that I can use it to construct other patterns.

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you'd capture an `awk` string function result, eg:

```
x = substr($1,3,5)
```

A simple example of capturing a user-defined function return value:

```
awk '
function dgrul( rl ) {
    rl = "abcde"
    return rl
}
BEGIN { print "x (before) :",x
        x = dgrul()
        print "x  (after) :",x
      }
'
```

This generates:

```
x (before) :
x  (after) : abcde
```